# Shared list among celery workers and Flask using python's multiprocessing

Tags: python, flask, celery, python-multiprocessing

I'm building a Flask application which relies on Celery to process some long running tasks. Each task will essentially append a dictionary to a shared list once it has finished processing - this list is shared by the celery workers and the routes of the Flask application. The Flask component essentially consists of a set of routes to retrieve the contents of the shared list and modify the order of the elements.

I thin I have successfully shared the list between the Celery workers using a Manager from the Python's multiprocessing module. However, the changes made to this list are not seen by the Flask application. Here is a minimal application which illustrates the issue:

```python
import os
import json

from flask import Flask
from multiprocessing import Manager
from celery import Celery

application = Flask(__name__)

redis_url = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')
if redis_url is None:
    redis_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

# Set the secret key to enable cookies
application.secret_key = 'some secret key'
application.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'

# Redis and Celery configuration
application.config['BROKER_URL'] = redis_url
application.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = redis_url

celery = Celery(application.name, broker=redis_url)
celery.conf.update(BROKER_URL=redis_url,
                CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis_url)

manager = Manager()
shared_queue = manager.list() # THIS IS THE SHARED LIST

@application.route("/submit", methods=['GET'])
def submit_song():
    add_song_to_queue.delay()
    return 'Added a song to the queue'

@application.route("/playlist", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_playlist():
    playlist = []
    i = 0
    queue_size = len(shared_queue)
    while i < queue_size:
        print(shared_queue[i])
        playlist.append(shared_queue[i])
    return json.dumps(playlist)

@celery.task
def add_song_to_queue():
    shared_queue.append({'some':'data!'})
    print(len(shared_queue))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

In the celery logs I can clearly see that the dictionaries are being appended to the list, and that the size of the list increases. However, when I access the /playlist route on my browser I always get an empty list.

Does anyone know how I can get the list to be shared among all the workers and the Flask application?

Comment: I presume you have two Python interpreters running so you cant. You could store the playlist in a database. That would be the best option any how.

Comment: @JoeDoherty I never considered that I'm using two separate interpreters. I really wanted to avoid using a database. Do you think swapping out Celery for Process(target=add_song_to_queue) calls might work? That would mean I would only be using 1 interpreter, I think.

Comment: I guess it would work but I couldn't recommend it. Python is not very well suited for multi-threading applications. We usually scale with more processes. How much traffic are you expecting to the app? You could use a simple KV store like Redis rather than a full blown RDBMS.

Comment: @JoeDoherty I just changed the sample code above to use Process and it works! I'm not expecting much traffic at all, but I'll look into using Redis as you suggested. I'm afraid too many processes will be created due to traffic; that's the reason I really want to use celery, so that I can limit the number of processes created. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad you have a working solution. Definitely look at some form of database. They are super useful in cases like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution by moving away from Celery and instead using multiprocessing.Pool as a task queue and shared memory through Manager as shown in sample code in the question. This link has an excellent example of how this solution can be integrated with Flask: http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/python-multiprocessing-as-a-task-queue.html

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
_pool = None

def expensive_function(x):
        # import packages that is used in this function
        # do your expensive time consuming process
        return x*x

@app.route('/expensive_calc/<int:x>')
def route_expcalc(x):
        f = _pool.apply_async(expensive_function,[x])
        r = f.get(timeout=2)
        return 'Result is %d'%r

if __name__=='__main__':
        _pool = Pool(processes=4)
        try:
                # insert production server deployment code
                app.run()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                _pool.close()
                _pool.join()
```

Comment: did you have any issues running your application with gunicorn or uwsgi?!

Comment: @leoschet is there any lib to use for windows like gunicorn? to allow async requests using flask?